# Trying to display ajax response in html

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, response

I am trying to display some ajax response that i receive from a controller each time i scroll at the bottom of the page.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    load++;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get-response',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "load" : load,
                "key" : key
            },
            success: function(response){
                var out = "";
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                    out += response[i];
                }
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = out;

            }
        });
}
```

The response i get is in JSON format and looks like this :
[image]

I am not sure how to traverse the result and display it in html appending each time the results are returned. Can anyone help me with what else i can write in this section to get the results displayed ?

```
success: function(response){
                var out = "";
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                    out += response[i];
                }
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = out;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have added `table` implementation, you can change into either `div`

```
    var out = "<table>";
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
        out +='<tr>';
        out +='<td>'+response[i].brand_name+'</td>';
        out +='<td>'+response[i].product_name+'</td>';
        out +='<td>'+response[i].selling_price+'</td>';
        out +='<td>'+response[i].mark_price+'</td>';
        out +='</tr>';
        out += response[i];
    }
    out += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Problem by displaying the objects in json, you just have to write

```
JSON.stringify(response[i])
```

Or you could use another for loop

```
for(var x: response[i]){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should 'pretty-print' it with the space indentation, suitable for viewing in HTML:

```
success: function(response){
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, '&nbsp').replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
    $("#response").css('font-family', 'courier');
};
```